# how to link my local repository to the remote repository in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I have tried the following command:
/c/Git $ git remote add origin"https://gitlab.com/mshahr1/0101010_d197.git"

and give the error:

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

What is the problem ? please answer this .

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you're in the right directory. Otherwise, there seems to be no .git folder.

```
git init 
git add . 
git commit -m "your msg" 
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/mshahr1/0101010_d197.git 
git push -u origin master
```

should be the normal workflow.